# Access buildConfigField from gradle in Android app

Tags: android, gradle, android-buildconfig

I am building a multi-app project in Android Studio and use Gradle for my versioning.

I use

```
versionName "1.0"
versionCode 2
versionNameSuffix = ".alpha1"
```

I also use

```
def getDate() {
    new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
}
```

and

```
buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_DATE', '\"' + getDate() + '\"'
```

and all works well.

I can access those though code using

```
String vN = BuildConfig.versionName;
int vC = BuildConfig.versionCode;
String bD = BuildConfig.BUILD_DATE;
```

One problem I am having is that I sometimes need to access this information from another application.

I can get versionName and versionCode with

```
PackageInfo pi = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
String vN = pi.versionName;
int vC = pi.versionCode;
```

is there any way to access BUILD_DATE from another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not readily.

The simplest approach would be to either switch from `buildConfigField` to `resValue`, or to put the same `getDate()` value in both a `buildConfigField` and `resValue`. `resValue` will let you define a string resource with your date. Then, the app that needs the value can use `getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication()` to get a `Resources` object, from which you can read in the string resource value.

If the rest of your code can work with the string resource, you could just switch from `buildConfigField` to `resValue`. If doing so would be inconvenient, having both the build date in `BuildConfig` and in a string resource would be a minor bit of data duplication but not a big problem IMHO.