# How to override BuildConfig from Android-Library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I have a Android Library and I am using it in app module. In library I use a BuildConfig.SPECIAL_VALUE.
I would like to override this BuildConfig in my app module build gradle.

I found similary question but It doesn't help me ([Access buildConfigField from gradle in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427385/access-buildconfigfield-from-gradle-in-android-app))
I try this but is not working:

My app module build.gradle:

```
android {


publishNonDefault true
compileSdkVersion 28
flavorDimensions "default"
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app....id"
    flavorDimensions "default"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED', 'false'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.productivity_mentor_release_config
        debuggable = false
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
    }
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = false
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED', 'true'
        debuggable = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
    }
    unitTest {
        testCoverageEnabled = false
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED', 'false'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
    }
}

productFlavors {
    develop {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"11"'
    }
    production {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"22"'
    }
    beta {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"33"'
    }
    roboTest {
        minSdkVersion 18
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"44"'
    }
}
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

And my library build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
flavorDimensions "default"
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
publishNonDefault true
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                 "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {}
    debug {}
    unitTest { }
}

productFlavors {
    develop {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"1"'
    }
    production {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"2"'
    }
    beta {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"3"'
    }
    roboTest {
        minSdkVersion 18
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'LOG_EVENTS_TO_REMOTE_ENABLED', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'SPECIAL_VALUE', '"4"'
    }
}
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

}

```
ext {
    google_services_version = '16.0.7'
}
```

Comment: You can't override build configs.

Comment: So what shout I do ?

Comment: Every module that you have in your project will generate one particular BuildConfig file, and they are independent from one another, so no overriding is possible in that sense. Why not just change the library gradle file?

Comment: I cannot change library gradle files because i have more than one app module which use this library